# Bluetooth headphones won't connect after last update involving pipewire

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones, pipewire

After my last update involving the libraries in the picture, my bluetooth headphones won't connect (the bluetooth mouse works fine).

Here are the libraries:
[image]
[image]

Now when I'm trying to connect the pc won't pair, the "waiting" text won't disappear and if I click again on pair, I get a `br-connection-busy` error.